# Mysqldb is not installing in flask Application am using pycharm

Tags: python, mysql

I am new in flask python development,I tried to use the following command below in **Pycharm**  to enable Mysql usage in my Application, but it's not working :

```
install Flask-mysqldb
```

It throws the following information after i enter the command, i dont know if i am missing something , but i already have mysql installed on my computer and i created all my databases but there's no successful installation message anywhere:

```
Collecting Flask-mysqldb
Collecting mysqlclient (from Flask-mysqldb)
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.10 in c:\users\huzy_kamz\pycharmprojects\myfirstflask\venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask-mysqldb)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.21 in c:\users\huzy_kamz\pycharmprojects\myfirstflask\venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->Flask-mysqldb)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=2.0 in c:\users\huzy_kamz\pycharmprojects\myfirstflask\venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->Flask-mysqldb)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.7 in c:\users\huzy_kamz\pycharmprojects\myfirstflask\venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->Flask-mysqldb)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.4 in c:\users\huzy_kamz\pycharmprojects\myfirstflask\venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->Flask-mysqldb)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\huzy_kamz\pycharmprojects\myfirstflask\venv\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->Flask>=0.10->Flask
-mysqldb)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysqlclient ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\huzy_kamz\pycharmprojects\myfirstflask\venv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\
huzy_k~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-8jxhwx\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.clos
e();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\huzy_k~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpefdo3cpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
  C:\Users\Huzy_Kamz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=
(1,3,12,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.12 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include" -IC:\Python27\include -Ic:\users\huzy_kamz\pycharmprojec
ts\myfirstflask\venv\PC /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
  _mysql.c
  _mysql.c(29) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\Huzy_Kamz\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit statu
s 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient, Flask-mysqldb
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\huzy_kamz\pycharmprojects\myfirstflask\venv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users
\\huzy_k~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-8jxhwx\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.cl
ose();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\huzy_k~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-4xug6v-record\install-record.txt --single-version-extern
ally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\huzy_kamz\pycharmprojects\myfirstflask\venv\include\site\python2.7\mysqlclient:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
    C:\Users\Huzy_Kamz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_inf
o=(1,3,12,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.12 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include" -IC:\Python27\include -Ic:\users\huzy_kamz\pycharmproj
ects\myfirstflask\venv\PC /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    _mysql.c(29) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\Huzy_Kamz\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit sta
tus 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\huzy_kamz\pycharmprojects\myfirstflask\venv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\huzy_k~1\\appdata\\loc
al\\temp\\pip-build-8jxhwx\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code,
 __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\huzy_k~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-4xug6v-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile -
-install-headers c:\users\huzy_kamz\pycharmprojects\myfirstflask\venv\include\site\python2.7\mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\huzy_k~1\appdata
\local\temp\pip-build-8jxhwx\mysqlclient\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From where do you run this:

```
install Flask-mysqldb
```

?

The nice tool must obtain all needed things by default. If no, try another tool. Try use **pip** from **Miniconda** with **PyCharm**.

Install Miniconda with default options https://conda.io/miniconda.html Create the new PyCharm project (for example 'myproject') and select **conda** as the environment manager. Just print new relevant paths by your hands, so project folder and environment folder will be created automaticaly, see 
[image: Project with conda]

Then open Anaconda Prompt from Windows Start Menu.

See [image: Anaconda Prompt]

Then run commands:

```
activate myproject
pip install flask-mysqldb
```

See [image: Install flask-mysqldb]

Also, you can install all packages which are needed for your project.

If you do not want use conda instead virtualenv, select virtualenv, but virtualenv from Miniconda, as far as Miniconda is more tested and work out of the box without such errors. You can use your usual python in your old project, and select Miniconda for new project, it is not dangerous. See example of select virtualenv from Miniconda: [image: virtualenv from Miniconda]

In new project open console by hit Ctrl+F12 and run:

```
pip install flask-mysqldb
```

Result is next:

```
Collecting flask-mysqldb
Collecting Flask>=0.10 (from flask-mysqldb)
  Using cached Flask-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting mysqlclient (from flask-mysqldb)
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.12-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting Werkzeug>=0.7 (from Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb)
  Using cached Werkzeug-0.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Jinja2>=2.4 (from Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb)
  Using cached Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting itsdangerous>=0.21 (from Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb)
Collecting click>=2.0 (from Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb)
  Using cached click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2>=2.4->Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb)
Installing collected packages: Werkzeug, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, itsdangerous, click, Flask, mysqlclient, flask-mysqldb
Successfully installed Flask-0.12.2 Jinja2-2.10 MarkupSafe-1.0 Werkzeug-0.14.1 click-6.7 flask-mysqldb-0.2.0 itsdangerous-0.24 mysqlclient-1.3.12
```

Comment: So does this mysql installation be available in my project i created earlier ?

Comment: This new mysql with conda do not available from the old project with virtualenv. But you can copy your python source py-files which you create and develop from old project to new project, and continue develop in new project. Also use Miniconda3 for Python3 or Miniconda2 for Python2.

Comment: so you mean , i start uising conda instaed of virtualenv

Comment: Yes. You can start use conda instead virtualenv. But more deep thing, Miniconda instead Microsoft Visual C++ for Python. You can use virtualenv, if you select virtualenv of Miniconda. Just you need more tested python with more tested pip.

Comment: You can have the several python installed in your system, and use other python for other project. So all your old projects will work with old python, and your new project will work with Miniconda.

Comment: how can i install miniconda , is it the on this link https://www.anaconda.com/download/ ?

Comment: Its like there's a difference between anaconda and miniconda , i saw another link for miniconda https://conda.io/miniconda.html and the one above

Comment: I update my answer. Install Miniconda from link https://conda.io/miniconda.html Miniconda is installed fast, and Anaconda is instaled slow, so use Miniconda.